# Using Seq functions on an IEnumerable

Tags: f#, ienumerable

I'm trying to apply Seq functions on an IEnumerable. More specifically, it's `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection` which implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`.

Since an F# `seq` is an IEnumerable, I thought I could write

```
let foo = myHtmlElementCollection |> Seq.find (fun i -> i.Name = "foo")
```

but the compiler will have none of it, and complains that *"The type 'HtmlElementCollection' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'"*.

However, the compiler willingly accepts the IEnumerable in a `for .. in ..` sequence expression:

```
let foo = seq { for i in myHtmlElementCollection -> i } |> Seq.find (fun i -> i.Name = "foo")
```

What do I need to do in order for the IEnumerable to be treated just like any old F# `seq`?

**NB:** This question is marked as a duplicate, but it's not. The linked "duplicate" is about *untyped* sequences (a seq from the seq { for ... } expression), whereas my question is about *typed* sequences.

Comment: Not quite, since he gets a seq<obj> from the seq { for ... } expression, whereas I get a typed seq.

Comment: That's because [§6.5.6 of the spec](http://fsharp.org/about/files/spec.pdf). The for loop knows that your `HtmlElementCollection` __has an Item property with a more specific return type__, ie. `HtmlElement`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

F#'s type `seq<'a>` is equivalent to the *generic* [`IEnumerable<'a>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `System.Collections.Generic`, but not to the *non-generic* [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use the [`Seq.cast<'a>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370344.aspx) function to convert from the non-generic one to the generic one:

```
let foo = myHtmlElementCollection
            |> Seq.cast<HtmlElement>
            |> Seq.find (fun i -> i.Name = "foo")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one mystery less. I'm still puzzled why `seq { for i in myHtmlElementCollection -> i }` works and gives me a seq<HtmlElement>. The HtmlElementCollection.Item property is typed, so I suspect Item is used somehow, but I would have thought that `seq { for ... }` would use an enumerator rather than ICollection.Count and Item.[i].

Comment: This is an incredibly useful answer. I had been struggling to understand why (when s is a string) let xs = [for c in s -> match c with
                                        | '1' -> 1uy
                                        | '0' -> 1uy
                                        | _   -> 0uy
                 ] would not work - the documentation doesn't make the IEnumerable vs IEnumerable<'a> distinction clear at all. Coming from a Haskell background this would never have occurred to me.